# Submitting text input erases page element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on something which lets you update text within the page. There is a submit button and it updates the text box above. Another way to trigger it is with the enter key when inside the text box input.

What is supposed to happen when the "Send" button or the enter key are pressed, is that the text will go in the text box. The problem is that when they are used, the text box above is also erased and the text blinks on there for a second. How do I make it so that the text says up in the upper text box?

Here is the code.:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
            function SendMsg() {
              document.getElementById('ScrollBox').innerHTML = document.send.msg.value + "<br />" + "<br />" + document.getElementById('ScrollBox').innerHTML;
              document.getElementById('TextInputBox').value = "";
            }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "ScrollBox" style="height:480px;width:240px;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto;"></div>
      <form name = "send" action = "">
         : <input type = "text" id = "TextInputBox" title = "Type what you want to send" name = "msg" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        SendMsg()"/>
         <input type = "submit" id = "btnSend" value = "Send" onclick = "SendMsg();"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

A bonus would be if there was a way to make the cursor go back to the text input every time it is submitted.

I am very new to JavaScript and this is my first project so I am very unsure how to proceed.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jack-bashford said, your form submit is causing a page refresh. For what you're trying to do, you don't actually need a form, so unless you're actually submitting that data to somewhere I'd suggest removing it.

Try this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="ScrollBox" style="height:480px;width:240px;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto;"></div>
    : <input type="text" id="TextInputBox" title="Type what you want to send" name="msg" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) SendMsg();"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Send" onclick="SendMsg();"/>
    <script>
      function SendMsg() {
        document.getElementById('ScrollBox').innerHTML = document.getElementById("TextInputBox").value + "<br />" + "<br />" + document.getElementById('ScrollBox').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('TextInputBox').value = "";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your form is submitting which by default refreshes the page if no `action` is given. Add an event listener to prevent this happening:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: Where would I add this? Is it also possible to put something in the action place to stop the refresh?

Comment: Add this at the global level in the page. Also, this prevents the refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you are using an submit input. This will break your page as it forces a reload.

See update below. Also added .focus() on your textinput after adding the value.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script type = "text/javascript">
            function SendMsg() {
              document.getElementById('ScrollBox').innerHTML = document.send.msg.value + "<br />" + "<br />" + document.getElementById('ScrollBox').innerHTML;
              document.getElementById('TextInputBox').value = "";
              document.getElementById("TextInputBox").focus();
              
            }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "ScrollBox" style="height:480px;width:240px;border:1px solid #ccc;overflow:auto;"></div>
      <form name = "send" action = "">
         : <input type = "text" id = "TextInputBox" title = "Type what you want to send" name = "msg" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13)
                        SendMsg()"/>
         <input type = "button" id = "btnSend" value = "Send" onclick = "SendMsg();"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```